# What RSS parser should I use in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, rss, atom-feed

I am searching an RSS parser written in PHP. The problem is not that I cannot find one. The problem is that there are too many and it's hard to decide which one to use (especially when I have no experience with them and to try them is too time consuming).

Can anybody recommend me a "good" RSS parser?

The following requirements are important to me (given in order of importance):

1. It's able to extract all information given in the feed (not only title, description and link but everything what is there, for example feeds author, feeds icon, items tags and so on).
2. It should be able to read not only RSS feeds but also Atom feeds.
3. It should be tolerant to "broken" RSS (Atom) feeds.
4. It should be simple to use.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rss+parser+php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My defacto answer will be "have you tried [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/)?", it's a very good XML parser but you'll have to have a look at their [demo](http://simplepie.org/demo/) to see how it handles broken feeds :-)

Comment: I downloaded 1.2 and tried out the demo, it throws up "Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplepie-simplepie-9a1ebc0\simplepie.inc on line 738"

Comment: You might want to consider raising an issue then -> https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/issues

Answer (score 5):

In addition to SimplePie already mentioned, there is [Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html) (which can be used standalone) and since this is XML anyway, you can also use [any of the native XML extensions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), like [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [XMLReader](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php).