# Grab full RSS Feed and not just excerpt

Tags: php, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What RSS parser should I use in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656767/what-rss-parser-should-i-use-in-php)

Basically I'm trying to pull the entire feed of one of the local news sites and display it in my site. I want it to grab all of the information from the feed(images included). For some weird reason it only allows me to grab a part of the actual content and not the entire page. Is there a way to grab all of the content? I know I've heard some sites may only provide a certain amount of info to their RSS Feed to. Is that true? Is there any way around this? Thanks

Here is the feed:
http://www.themonitor.com/common/rss/rss.php?

Comment: @Gordon Why it is closed? It's absolutely not a duplicate. These two questions has absolutely nothing in common. He doesn't want to parse RSS feed. He wants to get full RSS feed from partial RSS feed. It has nothing to do with classic RSS parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common for sites to limit the content in their RSS feeds.  In fact, most frameworks such as Wordpress offer plugins to do just that.  This limits the possibility of content theft.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a web service which automatically creates full RSS feed from your feed: [Full Text RSS Feed Builder](http://fulltextrssfeed.com/)